# compare two dataframe by specific column and return the rows not exist in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to comparing datafram df1 with df2 by column cust_id, and get all rows that not in df1

```
df1
  name   cust_id
1 cxa    c1001 
2 cxb    c1002
3 cxc    c1003
4 cxd    c1004

df2
  name   cust_id  qty
1 cxa    c1001    10 
2 cxb    c1002    20 
3 cxc    c1003    10
4 cxd    c1004    15
5 cxe    c1005    20
6 cxf    c1006    20

output
5 cxe    c1005    20
6 cxf    c1006    20
```

Comment: Checkout `Series.isin`. `df2[~df2['cust_id'].isin(df1['cust_id'].tolist()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to see rows from df2 with cust_id which does not appear in df1 (and value in 'name' column does not matter), you can do:

```
df2[~df2['cust_id'].isin(df1['cust_id'])]
```

Output:

```
   name cust_id  qty
5   cxe   c1005   20
6   cxf   c1006   20
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I expected

Answer (score 2):

try using `merge` with `indicator`:

```
df_new = df1.merge(df2, how='right', on=['cust_id'], indicator=True)
df_new[df_new['_merge']=='right_only']
```

---

```
    name    cust_id qty _merge
4   cxe     c1005   20  right_only
5   cxf     c1006   20  right_only
```

OR

```
d1 = df1.set_index(['cust_id'])
d2 = df2.set_index(['cust_id'])
d2[~d2.index.isin(d1.index)].reset_index()
```